# Location Suggestions in meetingTimeSuggestionResults

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I do a `FindMeetingTimes` without any `LocationConstraints` the suggestions include conference rooms that are remote to my Office Location for e.g., conf rooms in Cleveland while I'm located in Dallas.

I'm trying to understand how `FindMeetingTimes` works and how we can try to locate the best match of conf rooms.

Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Without any `LocationContraints` the API will include conference rooms across your organization.

You need to provide the API some context so it understands which locations make sense. This context is provided by the `LocationContraints` object. You'll need to populate it with the list of room resources that make sense for you:

```json
"locationConstraint": {
    "isRequired": true,
    "locations": [{
            "resolveAvailability": true,
            "displayName": "Room 1",
            "locationEmailAddress": "room1@contoso.com"
        },
        {
            "resolveAvailability": true,
            "displayName": "Room 3",
            "locationEmailAddress": "room3@contoso.com"
        },
        {
            "resolveAvailability": true,
            "displayName": "Room 3",
            "locationEmailAddress": "room3@contoso.com"
        }
    ],
    "suggestLocation": true
}
```